# PHP - Complicated Regex extraction

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have some strings to parse, and it's getting a little more complex.

```
<?php
$notecomments = '
This is the first of the notes, and so whatever comes later is appended.<br>
(<b>John Smith</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT</b><hr>This is a comment posted<br><br>(<b>Alex Boom</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT</b><hr>And let's put some more in here<br />with a new line.';

if(preg_match_all('/\(<b>(?:(?!\(<b>).)*/s', $notecomments, $matches)){
print_r($matches);
}

/* result of code:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (<b>John Smith</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT</b><hr>This is a comment posted<br><br>
            [1] => (<b>Alex Boom</b>) at <b class="datetimeGMT">2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT</b><hr>And let's put some more in here<br />with a new line.
        )

)
*/
?>
```

I'm able to loop through "appended" notes, since I have indicators to work with in the `preg_match_all` regex rules.

However, many of my notes have text before the first iteration from my `preg_match_all`.
(in this case: "This is the first of the notes, and so whatever comes later is appended.
")

**My first goal was met.**  Which is the result of my code above.  I'm extracting appended notes to the first note.

**My next goal** is to detect anything before the first iteration.  And that's where I'm stuck. (detecting anything before the first iteration, in my regex statement above)

Comment: Can you explicitly state in plain language what your matching/extraction criteria area are (i.e. I want to capture everything before the first `<br>` or everything before first `(<b>` or whatever.

Comment: Since in this case it's likewise cumbersome, you could consider the DOM methods to iterate over nodes (text, tags) and look for `b` and then the final `br` tag or a linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

i use preg_replace_callback with two regex for this
like

```
 $notecomments = "This is the first of the notes, and so whatever comes later is appended.<br>(<b>John Smith</b>) at <b class=\"datetimeGMT\">2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT</b><hr>This is a comment posted<br><br>(<b>Alex Boom</b>) at <b class=\"datetimeGMT\">2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT</b><hr>And let's put some more in here<br />with a new line.";
 $output=preg_replace_callback(array("~<b (.*?)>(.+?)</b>~si","~<b>(.+?)</b>~si"),function($matches){
if(isset($matches[2])){
  print_r($matches[2]."\n");
}else{
  print_r($matches[1]."\n");
}
return '';},' '.$notecomments.' ');
```

output:

```
 2012-02-07 00:00:20 GMT
 2013-02-07 00:08:06 GMT
 John Smith
 Alex Boom
```